# display: inline-block and 100% height to achieve 'floating'

Tags: css-float, width, css

I have a `<ul> <li>` and I require the use of `display: inline-block;`. This is required in order to "float" the li's whilst the last element is 100% wide of it's parent container and there could be any amount of li's (floating would mean the amount of li's is finite depending on the width of it's containing element). So the total width of the `<ul>` will be greater than the width of the viewport.

This is fine except I require the "floated" elements to multiline and I expect all elements which are not multi lined to be 100% height of the `<ul>`.

I can achieve what I want by setting the height of the `<ul>` in JS but this is something I really do not want to do.

Here is a JS fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/d5WBv/3/

Does anyone have a solution. I'm not sure if flexbox or `display: table;` can solve this but I cannot seem to get it to....

Thanks!

Comment: [how's this?](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/d5WBv/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The height works but, I need the last li to be 100% width of the viewport though (so the total UL is wider than the screen).

Comment: I don't think it is possible with pure css as if you need them to be the same height then adding either table or flex means that the child lis will take up the space of their parent rather than the viewport and any other way will make the height of the first 2 lis not be as tall. so either way you need js to calculate either the height or the width.  Just as an aside, why would you want the last cell to be as wide as the viewport?  if you had a small viewport you may make the other 2 cells really tall

Comment: This is acting as a self contained horizontal scrolling list in a page. And the last item in the list needs to be 100% wide.

Comment: do you have to use UL/LI? or you can change the DOM to DIV's?

Comment: The DOM can be changed!

Answer (score 3):

I guess, you mean that the li's all should have the same height?

If so, you could display them as table-cells:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also, check the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/d5WBv/9/).

Comment: This is what pete suggested in the above comment. I need the last li to be 100% wide though.

Answer (score 0):

I have a CSS solution for you, check out this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/zvKEz/)

DownSide: it requires to Double the `ul` `li` elements,
(one of them is for taking the real space in the document flow, (he don't render as we want but so will be hidden), and one of them is showed, on top of the other, with the display you want.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <ul class="Hidden">
        <li>This stays on one line</li>
        <li>And this</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed auctor libero neque, nec tristique metus rutrum et. Integer semper libero quis magna placerat, a posuere sem congue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed auctor libero neque, nec tristique metus rutrum et. Integer semper libero quis magna placerat, a posuere sem congue.</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="Visible">
        <li>This stays on one line</li>
        <li>And this</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed auctor libero neque, nec tristique metus rutrum et. Integer semper libero quis magna placerat, a posuere sem congue.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed auctor libero neque, nec tristique metus rutrum et. Integer semper libero quis magna placerat, a posuere sem congue.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Container
{
    position: relative;
}

.Hidden
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.Visible
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

ul
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    font-size: 0;
}
li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fefefe;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}

li:last-child
{
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}
```

Comment: I can see what you are doing here! I'd want to avoid doubling markup to achieve this, in fact I think I'd rather use the JS solution over increasing the DOM size. Thanks for the idea though.